# Beginners Question: Swift: NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: swift, nsurl, nsmutableurlrequest

- Would like to have some simple Stock Data in my project
- Using the rapidAPI for that

I have various beginner mistakes, which I am not capable to fix. Some help would be appreciated. Tried to google for it and read apple documentation but did not get far. Here is the code part:

```
import Foundation

struct StockDataManager  {

let headers = [
    "x-rapidapi-host": "yahoo-finance15.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": "MYAPIKEY"
]

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://yahoo-finance15.p.rapidapi.com/api/yahoo/qu/quote/AAPL/financial-data")! as URL,
                                        cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                    timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    

let session = URLSession.shared
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if (error != nil) {
        print(error)
    } else {
        let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        print(httpResponse)
    }
})

dataTask.resume()

}
```

I get the follwoing errors at this point:

```
request.httpMethod = "GET"
```

- Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
- Expected '(' in argument list of function declaration
- Expected '{' in body of function declaration
- Expected 'func' keyword in instance method declaration
- Expected declaration
- Invalid redeclaration of 'request()'

And here:

```
dataTask.resume()
```

- Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
- Expected '(' in argument list of function declaration
- Expected '{' in body of function declaration
- Expected 'func' keyword in instance method declaration

I am pretty sure this is basic understanding and sorry for that stupid simple question. Thanks in advance still for trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all don't use `NSURL` and `NS(Mutable)URLRequest` in Swift at all. Use the native types.

Any custom code must be run inside a function for example

```
struct StockDataManager  {
    func loadData(completion: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
        let headers = [
            "x-rapidapi-host": "yahoo-finance15.p.rapidapi.com",
            "x-rapidapi-key": "MYAPIKEY"
        ]
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://yahoo-finance15.p.rapidapi.com/api/yahoo/qu/quote/AAPL/financial-data")!,
                                          cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                          timeoutInterval: 10.0)
        
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
            } else {
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                print(httpResponse)
                completion(.success(data!))
            }
        })
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

The `loadData` function needs also a completion handler to process the asynchronously received data.

Comment: Btw big thanks for that help. Sorry for stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have code (request.httpMethod = "GET") which is not a declaration directly in struct.
Embed it in a func, like this:

```
func setRequest() -> NSMutableURLRequest {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(
        url: NSURL(string: "https://yahoo-finance15.p.rapidapi.com/api/yahoo/qu/quote/AAPL/financial-data")! as URL,
        cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
        timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    
    return request
}
```